# Error while trying to create C# code using wsdl.exe

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am trying to generate C# client code using Microsoft's wsdl.exe, here's the wsdl:

https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1443/EDTService/EDTService?wsdl

but I get this error while using it:

[image]

but when I try to use this WSDL on a soap UI client it works and shows the definitions and all.

this also doesn't work in visual studio. can someone comment on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You might try to download the file and then run wsdl on the local file.

Comment: @KlausGütter how can I do that? as downloading the file doesn't really work with wsdl.exe

Comment: See e.g. [How to download files from command line in Windows like wget or curl](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-or-curl)